# Can't cancel Facebook friend requests from awhile back

Tags: facebook

About 5-6 months ago, I sent out several requests to people. Unfortunately, I got a block placed on my account for about 30 days from sending anymore friend requests. I get banned sometimes though but that time, the friend requests did not completely cancel. They probably cancelled on their end but not on my end. If I view their profile on anything like on a members list in a group or on an event they are attending, it will say "friend request sent". However, when I move my mouse over their name or actually go to their full profile, it will say "add friend". Unfortunately, I can't seem to add them again because it keeps saying, "already sent a request to connect" and then when I refresh the page it will go back to "add friend".

There isn't always an option to cancel the friend request and when it is available and I click on it, it won't work either. I don't know what to do. I have tried to contact Facebook multiple times and have included detailed screenshots to the problem. I even posted this on places like Yahoo Answers and the community forum on Facebook and never really got too many responses. I tried to remove all of my imported contacts and the friend requests problem still remains.

Can anyone help me with this?

This seems to be a really complex problem that might even need programming or something done in that order. I really don't know what to do or where to look for help anymore. I really want this issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

No amount of programming is going to change the way Facebook works. You're right, you are blocked from "refriending" these people.

So why not send them a message asking them to friend you, if you really do know them?